# QGestureEvent for mouse

Tags: c++, qt

I write desktop application that works with map,
and I want to react on pan and long press events.
It is possible to use `QGestureEvent` on Qt/Linux/X11 with ordinary mouse?

I took [Qt gesture example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-gestures-imagegestures-example.html), it works on tablet,
but not reaction on press left mouse button and move (I expect that application recognizes it as tap or swipe event).

Then I added to  [Qt gesture example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-gestures-imagegestures-example.html) `app.setAttribute(Qt::AA_SynthesizeTouchForUnhandledMouseEvents, true);` at `main` and such code to `imagewidget.cpp`:

```
void ImageWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    e->ignore();
}
void ImageWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    e->ignore();
}
void ImageWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    e->ignore();
}
```

this code still works on tablet, but again no reaction on mouse on Linux/X11.

Any way to enable qgesture on linux/x11, should I write my own gesture recognition
for mouse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official way to make gestures out of mouse events in Qt is deriving from the `QGestureRecognizer` class, which allows to listen to relevant mouse events, set gesture properties accordingly, then trigger the gesture (or cancel it).

Here follows an example for pan gestures only, just to give an idea of what has to be done.

Have a `QGestureRecognizer` subclass like this:

```
#include <QGestureRecognizer>
#include <QPointF>
class PanGestureRecognizer : public QGestureRecognizer
{
  QPointF startpoint;
  bool panning;
public:
  PanGestureRecognizer() : panning(false){}
  QGesture *create(QObject *target);
  Result recognize(QGesture *state, QObject *watched, QEvent *event);
};
```

The `create` method has been overridden to return a new instance of our gesture of interest:

```
QGesture *PanGestureRecognizer::create(QObject *target)
{
  return  new QPanGesture();
}
```

The `recognize` method override is the core of our recognizer class, where events are passed in, gesture properties set, gesture events triggered:

```
QGestureRecognizer::Result PanGestureRecognizer::recognize(QGesture *state, QObject *, QEvent *event)
{
  QMouseEvent * mouse = dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
  if(mouse != 0)
  {
    if(mouse->type() == QMouseEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
      QPanGesture * gesture = dynamic_cast<QPanGesture*>(state);
      if(gesture != 0)
      {
        panning = true;
        startpoint = mouse->pos();
        gesture->setLastOffset(QPointF());
        gesture->setOffset(QPointF());
        return TriggerGesture;
      }
    }
    if(panning && (mouse->type() == QMouseEvent::MouseMove))
    {
      QPanGesture * gesture = dynamic_cast<QPanGesture*>(state);
      if(gesture != 0)
      {
        gesture->setLastOffset(gesture->offset());
        gesture->setOffset(mouse->pos() - startpoint);
        return TriggerGesture;
      }
    }
    if(mouse->type() == QMouseEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {
      QPanGesture * gesture = dynamic_cast<QPanGesture*>(state);
      if(gesture != 0)
      {
        QPointF endpoint = mouse->pos();
        if(startpoint == endpoint)
        {
          return CancelGesture;
        }
        panning = false;
        gesture->setLastOffset(gesture->offset());
        gesture->setOffset(mouse->pos() - startpoint);
        return FinishGesture;
      }
    }
    if(mouse->type() == QMouseEvent::MouseButtonDblClick)
    {
      panning = false;
      return CancelGesture;
    }
  }
  return Ignore;
}
```

Basically, we track mouse events, updating a couple of properties of our own (`panning` and `startpoint`) and the passed in gesture properties as well. For each mouse event type, we also return a [QGestureRecognizer::Result](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgesturerecognizer.html#ResultFlag-enum) . All other events are discarded (the method returns `Ignore`).

This code can be tested with the [Image Gestures Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-gestures-imagegestures-example.html), though: just add the class to the project and this line in the `ImageWidget` constructor:

```
QGestureRecognizer::registerRecognizer(new PanGestureRecognizer());
```

This should let the user grab the picture and move it around, using a mouse.

Comment: I was trying to use your code to create the same but for QSwipeGesture. If it's not too much to ask, could you see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76894217/subclassing-qgesturerecognizer-trouble-with-calculating-swipe-angle

Answer (score 0):

Look into this image widget gestures example. (search for mouseDoubleClickEvent)

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-gestures-imagegestures-imagewidget-cpp.html

Based on that you need to reimplement the required mouse events.

```
MyWidget::MyWidget() {
    ---
    ---
}

bool MyWidget::event(QEvent *ev)
{
    ---
    ---
}

void MyWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{


}
void MyWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{


}
```

And declare those two functions in header

```
void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
```

Comment: gesture Qt's example also not works for me on PC without touchpad. I also try to add to gesture example empty mouse event handlers, but changes nothing.